# How can I incorporate good-looking mathematical exposition into my question/answer?

Tags: support, faq

How can I incorporate good-looking mathematical exposition into my question/answer?

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)

Comment: I've created this FAQ entry because of [this question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/292/5240)

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE**: Code Golf now supports MathJax (see [the other answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23495/68942)), so this is no longer accurate; however, the other advice in the post is worth keeping around.

---

codegolf.SE does not use MathJax, because its load time is too high (see [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/5240)). But although there is not built-in support for LaTeX, you can visualize mathematical formulae in various ways

### Images

You can include mathematical formulae as images. There a basically three ways how to get such an image:

- Use the [preview of math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to create your formula, make a screenshot and crop it to the right size.
- Create a LaTeX document on your computer, make a screenshot and crop it to the right size.
- Use command line tools (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34054/5645))
- Use [MathURL](http://mathurl.com/) to create an image of the equation (fastest option for images)

### Symbols

Many math symbols are also available as plain text. You can create your formula by using copy-and-paste:

- [Wikipedia:Mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mathematical_symbols)
- [math.typeit.org](http://math.typeit.org/)

The most basic symbols that you might need are:

- Arrows: ← ↓ → ↑ ↔ ↵ ⇐ ⇓ ⇒ ⇑ ⇔
- Sets: ∈ ∉ ∅ ⊆ ⊂ ⊄ ∪ ∩
- Relations: ≠ ≤ ≥ ≈
- Logic: ¬ ∧ ∨ ∃ ∀
- More: ∫ ∞ ε Δ ⋅

Note that most platforms offer some kind of extended character input palette which makes this input method easier. (e.g. Character Viewer in OSX, Character Map in Windows)

### Pure ASCII

While this is the least elegant-looking option, it produces results intelligible to anyone who understands the corresponding mathematical symbols. Handy if you want to put equations in your source code comments.

- [asciiTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asciitex/) - Binary for Windows only, but it is available on Homebrew for OSX and should build for Linux.

Comment: Awesome! I've added a few details, will put in more later when I have more time.

Comment: Did you copy the symbols idea from me? Yay. I would like to suggest the [Window's Snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-capture-screen-shots#1TC=windows-8) for making screenshots. It works just like a program I made, but it's better because it is easier to snip an image. I was overjoyed when a professor showed this program to us for use in our Labs.

Comment: As far as posting images go, I think a simpler option than screenshots is [MathURL](http://mathurl.com)

Comment: As MathURL doesn't support https, I highly recommend (And with heavy bias) using [a-ta.co](https://a-ta.co/generator)

Comment: @ATaco Is this link outdated, or this page just down at the moment?

Comment: @musicman523 Just down for a quick maintenance, should be back up shortly.

Comment: Since MathJax is now enabled, this answer is no longer accurate in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Code Golf, as of [June 20th 2018](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16556/66833), has \$\LaTeX\$ enabled on both main and meta sites. A much more complete guide on how to use Mathjax can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but here are the basics for those not familiar:

- To include inline formula, enclose the formula with `\$`: `\$\sin x^2\$` is \$\sin x^2\$
- For displayed formula, use `$$`: `$$\frac {\log n} \pi$$` is

$$\frac {\log n} \pi$$

- For subscripts and superscripts, use `_` and `^`: `x_2` (\$x_2\$) and `5^2` (\$5^2\$)
- Most operations only work on the next character: `2^10` (\$2^10\$). In order to group multiple parts together, use `{}`: `2^{10}` (\$2^{10}\$). Notice the difference between \$x_i^2\$ and \$x_{i^2}\$ (`x_i^2` and `x_{i^2}`)
- Fractions. There are three ways to display fractions:

  - `\frac{a+1}{b+1}`: \$\frac{a+1}{b+1}\$
  - `\over` for more complex fractions: `{x^2+5x-6 \over 7sin(y^3)}` is \${x^2+5x-6 \over 7\sin(y^3)}\$
  - `\cfrac` for continued fractions: `\cfrac a b` is \$\cfrac a b\$
- Sums and products are `\sum` and `\prod` respectively: \$\sum\$, \$\prod\$. Use a superscript argument for the value on top and a subscript for the value underneath: `\sum_{i=0}^{10} i` is \$\sum_{i=0}^{10} i\$
- Special characters, such as `{`,  `_` etc. can be escaped by prefixing with a backslash: \$\{ \_ \$. A backslash should be `\backslash`
- Some common symbols: `\lt \gt \le \leq \ge \geq \times \div \pm \cdot \circ \to \infty` are \$\lt \gt \le \leq \ge \geq \times \div \pm \cdot \circ \to \infty\$
- Some common functions: `\sin \tan \cos \lim` are \$\sin \tan \cos \lim\$. You can use subscripts to change limits: `\lim_{x \to 0}` is $$\lim_{x \to 0}$$

---

Some slightly less common things:

**Matrices**

Use `$$\begin{matrix}…\end{matrix}$$` In between the `\begin` and `\end`, put the matrix elements. End each matrix row with `\\`, and separate matrix elements with `&`. For example,

```
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
```

produces

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & x & x^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & z & z^2 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

**Aligned equations**

Often people want a series of equations where the equals signs are aligned. To get this, use `$$\begin{align}…\end{align}$$`. Each line should end with `\\`, and should contain an ampersand (`&`) at the point to align at, typically immediately before the equals sign. For example,

```
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + 2x - 1 & = x^2 + 2x + 1 - 2 \\
& = (x + 1)^2 - 2
\end{align}$$
```

produces

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + 2x - 1 & = x^2 + 2x + 1 - 2 \\
& = (x + 1)^2 - 2
\end{align}$$

**Definitions by cases**

Use `$$\begin{cases}…\end{cases}$$`. End each case with a `\\`, and use `&` before parts that should be aligned. For example,

```
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x-1) + f(x-2), & \text{ if } x > 2 \\
1, & \text{ if } x = 1 \text{ or } x = 2
\end{cases}$$
```

produces

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x-1) + f(x-2), & \text{ if } x > 2 \\
1, & \text{ if } x = 1 \text{ or } x = 2
\end{cases}$$